# What to use: Callback, AjAX or simple Javascript in Asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, javascript, callback

I am at a bit of a loss as far as what is the best tool for the job would be:

What I need:
A parent page has a link when clicked a `pop-up` will pop up with a `gridview` and a `save` button.

If the user saved the `gridview`, the parent page should refresh and change, in other words, I need to be able to pass data between client and server. Perhaps, I should mention that `Save` button will save the data from the `gridview` in the database, and I would like the pop-up to be closed, and the parent page refreshed.

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 and currently have no AJAX library installed. I looked at `CallBack` in ASP.NET and inclined to use it as it seems the easiest in this case.

EDIT: perhaps I should also mention that I would like the parent page to be inactive while the child window is up......

What would you recommend to use?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely use Javascript for this. Depending on whether you want to open a new window or use a pseudo-popup-dialog using javascript. For the former you would have some javascript on both pages interacting with each other, which while simple, is a bit ugly. For the latter approach, you would used Ajax to do the save, and then use javascript to refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks. What about ICallbackEventHandler interface? Any experience with it?